# Custom accessory view button - wrong row selected

Tags: iphone

I have implemented the accessory view of a UITableViewCell as a button, in the 
button's selector method i have the following code

```
   - (UIButton *) makeDetailDisclosureButton
   {
       UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom.png"];
  [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

   [button addTarget: self
           action: @selector(accessoryButtonTapped:withEvent:)
         forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      return ( button );
    }


  - (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
   {
       NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];
   if (indexPath != nil)
   {
    [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
  }
}
```

However sometimes the wrong row is being selected, ie if I tap on row 0 in the table i get
row = 1 actually being selected. The code above is quite well known as a solution for
a custom accessory view but it is proving unreliable. Is there something else i need to do here?

Comment: What do you mean by "Sometimes the wrong row is selected" ? What abt other times ?

Comment: the correct row is selected all other times ie  if i have 2 rows in the table and tap on row 0 sometimes about 1 in 10 row =1 is selected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
- (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)button.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]; 
    [self tableView:self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

The idea here is pretty basic. Button's superview should give me `cell.contentView` and it's superview is the `cell`. There is lovely helper method `indexPathForCell:` which will give us the index path which we can use to pass to the delegate method.

Comment: it's right, but little bug: instead of button.superview.superview use button.superview

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong seen in your code but you can refer [this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/) for reference.

**Difference I see in your code and in tutorial is**

```
 - (void) accessoryButtonTapped: (UIControl *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *) event //Your event
 - (void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event //In tutorial.
```

This does not make difference but still just a thought.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have at

```
tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:
```

method?

Anyhow, I wouldn't mess with the touches to get the index path.

Instead I'd tag the button with the [indexPath row] and then pass the tag to the other method.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem: The index path row in tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: was consistently wrong for -- in my case -- every 5th row of the table view.

e.g., tapping the Detail Disclosure button for row 4 correctly gave me indexPath.row = 3; but tapping row 5 *also* gave me indexPath.row = 3.

My mistake related to having set incompatible row heights for my custom UITableViewCell.

i.e., I set the custom row height to 56 in the UITableViewCell's Size Inspector, but I forgot that I earlier had set the row height programmatically in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: as a multiple of tableView.rowHeight. The default tableView.rowHeight (editable in the UITableView's Size Inspector) is 44, and that 'clash' apparently caused the problem.

I resolved my problem by setting the row height fields to 56 in the Size Inspectors of both the UITableView & the UITableViewCell and commenting out the tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method.