# Perform segue with accessoryButton

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am doing master + detail pages. I have successfully made tapping the cell rows in the master page jump to detail page, using the code below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MasterToDetail" sender:indexPath];
}
```

However becuase my master page cell rows also have accessory buttons, i need to make these buttons able to jump to the detail page too through tapping. So i implemented code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MasterToDetail" sender:self];
}
```

Howver the details dispalyed is not correct. It always shows the first detail data in the datalist. I changed sender:self to sender:indexPath also no working.

I used stackoverflow answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234373/how-i-can-use-the-detail-disclosure-button-whith-storyboard#) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227851/custom-accessory-view-button-wrong-row-selected#). I am a beginner, so some concepts still no clear sorry.

**Edited**
- preparesegue for masterviewcontroller.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DetailViewController *detailController =segue.destinationViewController;
    SearchDataDetail *bug = [self.bugs objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
    detailController.detailItem = bug;


}
```

-detailviewcontroller.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "SearchData.h"
#import "SearchDataDetail.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    self.rateView.notSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shockedface2_empty.png"];
    self.rateView.halfSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shockedface2_half.png"];
    self.rateView.fullSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shockedface2_full.png"];
    self.rateView.editable = YES;
    self.rateView.maxRating = 5;
    self.rateView.delegate = self;

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.titleField.text = self.detailItem.data.title;
        self.rateView.rating = self.detailItem.data.rating;
        self.imageView.image = self.detailItem.fullImage;
    }

}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTitleField:nil];
    [self setRateView:nil];
    [self setImageView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (void)rateView:(RateView *)rateView ratingDidChange:(float)rating {
    self.detailItem.data.rating = rating;
}

@end
```

Comment: please paste your code how you are displaying data in detail page.

Comment: Why not call didSelect on accessoryButtonTapped then use the indexPath?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to following statement

```
SearchDataDetail *bug = [self.bugs objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
```

In this `self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row` will work only for only for row selection
not for accessoryButton tap.

You can solve it by two easy way

1. Declare a variable in .h file to store indexPath and use it to pass selected indexPath.
2. Pass indexPath in sender

All the best..